# Shell script to generate random number between two number or range using echo $RANDOM

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to identify some more options that I can use with  $RANDOM to generate the random number from specific range and not able to find one. can some one please help me with it. echo $RANDOM generates the number from shell but its random and not specific to my range. I want to generate random in the range from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU sort:

```
rand=$( seq $start $end | sort -R | head -1)
```

Calls external tools, so will be a few milliseconds slower than performing arithmetic with $RANDOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using a `shell` function :

```
intrandfromrange() { echo $(( ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) ) + $1 )); }
intrandfromrange 1 100
```

### EXPLANATIONS

- `foo() { }` is a skeleton for shell functions.
- `$((...))` gives the result of the enclosed [arithmetic expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).
- `%` stands for modulo, the remainder of a division operation.
- `$1` & `$2` are the first and the second arguments of the function.
- The rest is just simple arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks Sputnick, can you provide some explanation on the snip.

Comment: Thanks for reply. So ( RANDOM % ($2 - $1 +1 ) will be take one random number and it will do MOD with ($2-$1 +1) output, in my case its 100-1+1?

Comment: This won't give uniform results. You're more likely to get values 1-68 than 69-100 (because $RANDOM isn't evenly divisible by 100). In effect, it's a weighted die.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
 printf '%s\n' {1..100} | shuf | head -1
```

Comment: This should give better results. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to 3rd generation languages :

```
python -c 'import random; print(random.randint(1, 100))'
```

Comment: yeah PHP is also easy, it has rand function where you can specify the range but the device that I am testing with doesn't have that facility.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "shuf | head -1". "**shuf -n 1**"

Also:

**seq 1 100 | shuf -n 1**

A similar function could be:

```
rnd () {
seq $1 $2 | shuf -n ${3:-1}
}
```

So rnd 1200 5000 5 will output 5 random numbers between 1200 and 5000. For whenever one needs some. No need to specify 1 if you need just one and you're in a hurry.